# Errant comma with biblatex publist when omitting name

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-publist

I would like to use `biblatex` and the `publist` style to present a list of publications that omits my own name.  But when I do so, I get two styles (see comma before *et al.*) depending on whether my name appeared first in the author list or not.

For example:

[image: bib]

#### Questions:

1. Should there be a comma before *et al.* in this case? (I think probably not.)
2. Why is there a difference?  Is this a bug?
3. How do I remove the inconsistency?  I would prefer no comma (unless there is good evidence for the other case).

#### MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{paperA,
    booktitle = {Proceedings},
    year = {2014},
    author = {First, Author and Second, Author and Third, Author and Fourth, Author and Fifth, Author},
    title = {AAA Title of Paper},
}
@inproceedings{paperB,
    booktitle = {Proceedings},
    year = {2013},
    author = {Second, Author and First, Author and Third, Author and Fourth, Author and Fifth, Author},
    title = {BBB Title of Paper},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true,sorting=nyt,bibstyle=publist]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}
\omitname{First} % Omit author with last name "First"

\begin{document}

\null\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can

```
\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=\value{liststop}\AND
              \ifmorenames}
    {\andothersdelim\biblcstring{andothers}}
    {}}
```

To get rid of the comma before "et al." (I prefer not to have it).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{paperA,
    booktitle = {Proceedings},
    year = {2014},
    author = {First, Author and Second, Author and Third, Author and Fourth, Author and Fifth, Author},
    title = {AAA Title of Paper},
}
@inproceedings{paperB,
    booktitle = {Proceedings},
    year = {2013},
    author = {Second, Author and First, Author and Third, Author and Fourth, Author and Fifth, Author},
    title = {BBB Title of Paper},
}
@inproceedings{paperC,
    booktitle = {Proceedings},
    year = {2013},
    author = {Second, Author and First, Author},
    title = {CCC Title of Paper},
}
@inproceedings{paperD,
    booktitle = {Proceedings},
    year = {2013},
    author = {First, Author},
    title = {DDD Title of Paper},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true,sorting=nyt,bibstyle=publist]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\omitname{First} % Omit author with last name "First"

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=\value{liststop}\AND
              \ifmorenames}
    {\andothersdelim\biblcstring{andothers}}
    {}}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. And I think this *is* a bug. If one wanted a comma before "et al" one should make your adjustment and set `\andothersdelim` to `{\addcomma\space}`. At any rate the output should be the same in both cases.

Comment: @PaulStanley You are probably right. And good point about `\andothersdelim`.